# How to save and reload image using ALAsset?

Tags: ios, image, xcode4, camera, alassetslibrary

I'm writing an app that lets users take Photos and assign them to a Device. For this I need to  be able to store the URL of the taken Picture and reload the Picture afterwards.

I know there have been several discussions on that, but strangely none of the Ansers helped me...

So here's my Code for saving an Image:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    ALAssetsLibrary * library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
    UIImage * image;

    // Request to save Image
    if ([picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL * assertURL, NSError * error){
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"PictureSaveErrorTitle", @"Title if saving picture fails") 
                                                                 message:NSLocalizedString(@"PictureSaveErrorMessage", @"Message if saving picture fails") 
                                                                delegate:nil 
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"PictureSaveErrorOK", @"OK if saving picture fails") 
                                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
            } else {
                [self setUserImage:[assertURL absoluteString]];
                [imageOfDevice setImage:image];
            }
        }];
    } else {
        image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        [self setUserImage:[[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] path]];
    }

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

And this is for reloading the Image:

```
if (userImage != nil) {
        ALAssetsLibrary * library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library assetForURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:userImage] 
                 resultBlock:^(ALAsset * asset){
                     [imageOfDevice setImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset thumbnail]]];
                 }
                failureBlock:^(NSError * error){
                    NSLog(@"cannot get image - %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }];
}
```

Does anybody see any fault?

Thanks for helping,

sensslen

Comment: I'm still looking for anybody with a great Idea to help me I'm still stuck with this silly Problem. Actually this can't be so difficult. There are Plenty of Apps doing something with Photo Library, aren't there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simple solution is that you are passing in the absoluteString to instead of the NSUrl.

This code works for me inside picker did finish.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
if( [picker sourceType] == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera )
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:image.CGImage orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)image.imageOrientation completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error )
    {
        NSLog(@"IMAGE SAVED TO PHOTO ALBUM");
        [library assetForURL:assetURL resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset )
        {
            NSLog(@"we have our ALAsset!");
        } 
                failureBlock:^(NSError *error )
         {
             NSLog(@"Error loading asset");
         }];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Well actually I decided to save the Pictures to the App specific directory and this is working by now. Nontheless I tried out your Code. I am able to save an Image - this was never a Problem. the Problem is to reload it... I wasn't able to receive the thumbnail of the Image... Could you please show the code to load an Image?

Comment: simply replace NSLog( "we have our ALAsset!" ); with 
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[asset defaultRepresentation].fullResolutionImage];

Comment: Hmm, sounds simple... I thought I had tried that, but most likely I did something else.... Nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Comment: @AnthonyMcCormick, What is AssetLibraryUtil? I get an error "use of undeclared identifier" when I use it.

Comment: @T.J. it was just a util i used for getting a singleton reference to AssetLibrary I have replaced the code above to only reference the ALAssetsLibrary.